# What makes a hand saw great?

Tags: hand-saw

In writing an answer for [How do experts make dovetails by hand that fit so well?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3672/how-do-experts-make-dovetails-by-hand-that-fit-so-well), I realized that there is much more to say than "get a good saw."  I have some old saws that I am trying to refurbish, but also just purchased a Veritas Dovetail saw ($60), which is performing so much better than the box store models.  While shopping for this saw I also found Rob Cosman's $250 saw.

While some of the cost differences between these saws may simply be marketing, I know that a number of design features contribute to a superior saw. So what makes a great saw great?

Comment: Sharpness, straightness, and comfort.

Answer (score 8):

> I know that a number of design features contribute to a superior saw. So what makes a great saw great?

The number one required thing for a hand saw is that is cuts straight.  This isn't something that you can tell just from looking at it (usually - if the saw plate is bent then it clearly won't cut straight).  A saw will cut straight when it's filed correctly and set evenly (to say nothing of the user's ability to cut a straight line).

Next, a great saw is made of great steel.  By this, I mean a good spring steel that can hold an edge.  If you've ever seen someone "pluck" a hand saw to have it make that *twong* noise, they're testing the springiness of the steel.  Modern, boutique saws use good steel with re-file-able teeth.  Big-box makers usually use induction-hardened teeth, which cannot be easily resharpened in the home shop.

The final thing that sets a great saw apart is the fit and finish.  If you look at a junky big-box saw, it's all plastic, aluminum, and rubber with little thought to aesthetics and ergonomics.  A properly-made hand saw is beautiful to look at and feels wonderful in the hand, even after sawing away for an hour.  Great saws age very well and develop a nice patina.  Cheap saws look like junk no matter how old they are.

---

There are of course varying degrees of greatness, even within great sawmakers.  Veritas makes some excellent saws at a good price point because they are able to automate a lot of the processes that go into it.  Someone like Rob Crossman, Bad Axe, or Lie-Nielsen uses processes that are more labor-intensive, thus have a higher cost.  Also, you are paying for a name for some of these as well.

There are plenty of vintage/antique saws that can be made to work just as well as a new saw.  Take a look at this [Lumberjocks forum thread](http://lumberjocks.com/topics/27984) if you don't believe me.

Comment: Good call regarding the Veritas saw.  I saw a youtube video by Cossman showing how he makes the saw handles (he has the saw blades made elsewhere). They are really labor intensive.

Comment: An item you mentioned in the comment but not the answer is comfort. Some saw handles just don't fit all hands, or aren't at the best angle for all users.

Comment: `A properly-made hand saw is beautiful to look at and feels wonderful in the hand,` did this not address the comfort aspect? :)