# Bending birch plywood

Tags: plywood, twist

I have a largish piece of birch ply (120cm by 60cm) that warped -- one corner is 2cm off the flat plane.  I cannot replace this piece, so I'd like to try and bend it back to a flatter condition.  I assume that heat and steam, or both, might be how to do the trick, so I'd like to ask:

- if I apply (dry) heat, should I apply to the cupped side or the side that cups out?
- same question for steam: on the side that cups in or the side that cups out?
- what about using dry heat on one side and steam on the other?

I can easily live with the piece cupping a it towards the non show side. I know I could just try and see, but since I have a 50% chances of getting it wrong I'd like to improve my odds!

Comment: We have multiple previous Q&As on basically the same topic. Users are required to search first because SE doesn't allow repeat/duplicate Questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I flatten out a cupped piece of 3/4" plywood for a wood counter top base?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/how-can-i-flatten-out-a-cupped-piece-of-3-4-plywood-for-a-wood-counter-top-base)

Comment: nope, it does not answer my question.

Comment: That's an automated response from my close vote. It's just one of the previous Questions this could be considered a duplicate of.